# attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'w' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am working with an object oriented set-up in lua and despite checking fields for not being nil i recieve the error attempt "to perform arithmetic on field 'w' (a nil value)"

```lua
grid = { w=1, h=1, l=1, tiles = {}}
    function grid:new(obj)
         if obj then o = obj else o = {} end
         setmetatable(o, self)
         self.__index = self
         if o.w and o.h and o.l then
             o.tiles = {tile:new()}
             for i = 2, (o.w*o.l*o.h), 1 do table.insert(o.tiles, tile:new()) end
         end
         return o
    end
```

Expected to work properly due to the check if the fields are not nil, but for some reason the fields o.w, o.l and o.h seem to be nil.

Comment: Try making `o` a local variable.

Comment: Probably both `grid:new()` and `tile:new()` use the same global variable `o`

Comment: `self.__index = self` should be run before `setmetatable(o, self)`

Comment: @dualed - Why ?

Comment: Essentially because [the manual says it's good practice and I agree](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4) (2nd to last paragraph), not an answer to the problem, just a comment.